# why $C$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology

I have some confusion in **Rudin** book

My confusion is given below and marked in red colour

[image]

**My doubt**: why $C$ is  compact ?

**My attempt** : I know for  each $x \in K$there exist  an  open neighbourhood $G$  and for

each $x \in U$  there exist an open neighbhourhood $W_{p_1}$

Closure $G$ and closure $W_{p_1}$ are compact since both are open cover

It is given that $K \subset U \implies U^c \subset K^c$

$C$ is complement  of U that mean $C= U^c$

$K^c$ is noncompact   since $K$ is compact

so $C \subset$ noncompact set $\implies$ $C$ is not  compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C$ need not be compact here. What's compact are the sets
$$C \cap \overline{G} \cap \overline{W}p,$$
each of which are subsets of the compact set $\overline{G}$ ($G$ is defined to be a set with compact closure). There's no need for $C$ to be compact (it's just the index set); the finite intersection property is being used with respect to the compact subspace $\overline{G}$.